# modulus of complex number and inequality

Tags: complex-numbers

While going through an example related to modulus of complex number. Fig attached

[image: example]

I got almost all steps, however got stuck as how we get $OP=|z|=|\frac{1}{2}((z+4)+(z-4))|$

Any help is really appreciated, also any resources that help me to learn these concepts will also be helpful.

Thank you,
Arif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that: $$|\frac{1}{2}((z+4)+(z-4))| = |\frac{1}{2}(z+4+z-4)| = |\frac{1}{2}(2z)| = |z|$$

There is a **typo in the question** as well (*Where?* You have a minus sign instead of a plus sign in the modulus).

Comment: typo corrected, @Rohan Please any resources to help learn such concepts related to complex number will be of great help. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle complex numbers as vectors thus:

$$\vec{SP}=\vec{SO}+\vec{OP}=4+z$$

thus

$$SP=|z+4| $$